# Extract array values from Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, json.net

I have this Json:

```json
{
    "DataType": "Calibration_Symptoms",
    "playerHeight": 1.6739861965179443,
    "armSpan": 1.572389006614685,
    "calibratedHeadPosition": {
        "x": 0.10129322111606598,
        "y": 1.6739861965179443,
        "z": -0.01975761353969574
    },
    "symptomSeverity": 0,
    "scat5SymptomsQs": [1, 2, 3],
    "rightHanded": true,
    "rightFooted": true,
    "testType": false,
    "trialSymptomsQs": {
        "Gait": [1, 2, 3],
        "Balance1": []
    }
}
```

I deserialized it with `var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseString);`.

I'm now trying to extract the array values in `scat5SymptomsQs`. How do I do that?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to deserialize it to dictionary and not a class representing this structure?

Comment: values["scat5SumptomsQs"] ?

Comment: Ultimately I'll have different structures so I'd like to deserialize to something common before going to a class structure. Also, to know what class structure to use I need the "DataType". If there's a better way to do this I'd be keen to hear it.

Comment: If not desterilizing to a specific type then just stick with the `JObject` type.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary<string,object>` is a wrong type. Create a class that represents the object.

```
class Data
{
    public List<int> scat5SymptomsQs { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can:

```
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

If you don't want to create the object then please see [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm).

```
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

(...)

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

IList<int> x = o["scat5SymptomsQs"].Select(t => (int)t).ToList();
```